# Как отобразить перевод строки до загрузки страницы?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть примерно такая страничка:

```
router.get('/', (req,res) => {
    async_multiple_callbacks(result => {
        res.write(`<script>document.writeln(${result});</script>`);
    });
});
```

Т.е. - по get запросу вызывается функция, которая много раз вызывает callback, результат работы которого мне нужно увидеть на этой странице по мере поступления. Я вспомнил о древнем способе показать пользователю данные до загрузки страницы - `document.write`. Но мне хотелось бы отделить друг от друга выводы разных callbackов переводами строк. Как мне это сделать?
Вот это всё не работает (т.е. визуально текст всё равно слитный):

```
document.writeln("");
document.write("<br/>");
document.write("\r\n");
```

Comment: Это не Angular у вас там жрёт переводы строк? А иначе так document.writeln("<br/>") должно работать.

Comment: @VladislavPyatkov Вы прочитали только половину вопроса. "До загрузки страницы" тут ключевой момент. Angular у меня не используется, приведенный код - это nodejs (express), в тэги не стал ставить потому что тот же самое на любом языке можно проделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рецепт оказался прост. `\r\n` не работает, потому что браузер ждет html и игнорирует переводы строк и пробелы, а `<br/>` не работает, потому что браузер ждет полной загрузки страницы, чтоб начать рендерить html. Значит надо сказать браузеру, что мы даем ему не html, а plain text, тогда все становится гораздо проще:

```
router.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.header("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    async_multiple_callbacks(result => {
        res.write(result+"\r\n\r\n");
    });
});
```

И не надо никаких `document.write`. При загрузке plain текста браузер и так всё сразу отображает по мере поступления, и переводы строк отображаются нормально.